# Subversion "Working copy locked" problem

Tags: c++, svn, netbeans

After checking out a copy of a C++ project from subversion and doing any modifications I am getting a

> org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException:
>   Working copy
>   '/home/alex/NetBeansProjects' locked

error when trying to commit (yes, I use NetBeans Subversion client). This happened after I have deleted an unused folder from the repository via command line "svn remove -m" command. The folder contained one c++ source file, which not used in the project any more. I have tried doing Cleanup Local copy but with no result.

Any suggestions to why this might be happening and how to fix it?

Forgot to mention: I use Ubuntu and Sun Java

**Managed to resolve the issue:**
Deleted the local copy, closed NetBeans, checked it out **via command line**, added to files changes manually (with vim), commited. After this opened the project in Netbeans and finally could commit from it. Now everything works.

Comment: Glad to hear you solved it. One potential factor: are the minor versions of the built-in and command-line SVN clients the same, i.e. both 1.6.x? You can break working copies by using clients that assume different working copy formats - one will upgrade the other's format, and the other will stop working - although you usually get different errors.

Comment: Should not be the issue with Netbeans - it uses the "main" svn installation in /usr/bin

Answer (score 6):

I think, there are some locks left from a previous operation where you (accidently?) interrupted subversion while working.

Take your command line and try a `svn cleanup`. This should remove any locks present.

Comment: Didn't help as well.
On the other hand, I have tried committing the changes via command line "svn commit" and it worked perfectly. After updating the Netbeans client still refuses to commit any new changes. Seems to be a Netbeans thing then.

Comment: @alex: in your question, you write that you removed a file using command line and now the netbeans integrated client fails when committing. Did you try to do an `update` from the netbeans client?

Comment: Yes, I did try updating, checking out a new copy and checking out a new copy and then updating (and doing cleanups in-between in different variations)

Comment: @alex: even checking out a new working copy didn't help? that would have been my final guess: throw away everything and check out new. In your case, something must have gone massively wrong. Did you close netbeans, then checked out a fresh working copy and restarted netbeans?

Comment: Yep, didn't help though. On the other hand managed to resolve the ting myself now (see question editing). Thanks for trying to help though!